# How to give a represantation to veriables from each group using LASSO

Tags: lasso, glmnet, regularization, glmmlasso

I'm trying to apply LASSO regression on my data set in order to choose the best variables. However, my variables (44 to be accurate) come from 7 different groups, is there any option to give a "representation" to each group?

Comment: Could you say more specifically what you mean by "give a representation to each group"?

Comment: Have a look at group lasso.

Comment: I have a data set of 7 microbe phyla in each phyla I have approximately 10 microbes. I want to choose one or more microbes from each phyla to generate a specific response